# PHP str_getcsv getting Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I'm having a lot of trouble getting rid of this Undefined offset notice while using `str_getcsv` to read a CSV file and assign keys to it.

I've tried `isset` and `array_key_exists` which has been mentioned in other threads. `isset` did resolve undefined index notices but I can't remove the undefined offset notices:

```
$file = file("lookup.csv",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv",$file, array_fill(0, count($file), ';'));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
    foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
        $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);  
    }
$numberOfRows = count($csv);
$numberOfColumns = count(current($csv));
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= $numberOfRows; $i ++ ) {  // first loop to run thru to find correct sku template name in csv file
      if ( $csv[$i]['sku'] === $sku ) { // if sku matches  // Getting Undefined offset on this line
        for ( $j = 0; $j <= $numberOfColumns; $j++) {  // second loop to create variables from header line
            ${$keys[$j]} = isset($csv[$i][$keys[$j]]) ? $csv[$i][$keys[$j]] : ''; //  // Getting 2 Undefined offset notices on this line
            }
        }
    }
```

The CSV file in question does have some blank cells.  Those blank cells will be maintained (I can't do anything about that).

Please can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: try this $file = file('lookup.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last element in the array, it sometimes is an empty item as an extra line in the file is picked up due to a new line character at the end of the actual last line.

```
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv",$file, array_fill(0, count($file), ';'));
array_pop($csv);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - Unfortunately it did not make any difference, the undefined offset is still there.

I also manually removed the last empty line from the csv file to see if that changed anything but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I actually managed to figure it out myself.

The solution was to add isset - just in case it helps anyone else, here is my solution:

```
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= $numberOfRows; $i ++ ) {

    $csv[$i]['sku'] = isset($csv[$i]['sku']) ? $csv[$i]['sku'] : ''; // <-- isset added

      if ( $csv[$i]['sku'] === $sku ) {

        for ( $j = 0; $j <= $numberOfColumns; $j++) {

                $keys[$j] = isset($keys[$j]) ? $keys[$j] : ''; // <-- isset added

                $csv[$i][$keys[$j]] = isset($csv[$i][$keys[$j]]) ? $csv[$i][$keys[$j]] : '';

                ${$keys[$j]} = $csv[$i][$keys[$j]];
            }
        }
    }
```